# How to update the same record more than once in the same update query?

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2012/T-SQL, specifically Management Studio.

I am provided with a table (we'll call it **trackingInfo**) which looks like this:

```
po_no   tracking_no
1       ABC
2       DEF
2       GHI
```

I am attempting to insert the tracking_no data into a table (we'll call it **purchaseOrders**) in the following way:

```
po_no   notes
1       #ABC
2       #DEF, #GHI
```

(Please note that I cannot change the structure of either the **trackingInfo** data I am given or the **purchaseOrders** table in which I am trying to insert the information. I am limited to the above structures.)

I have an update query that works perfectly for instances where the dataset **trackingInfo** contains only a single tracking_no per po_no (such as po_no 1). However, in cases where there are more than one tracking_no per po_no (such as above with po_no 2), the update query I am using is failing to append the second tracking_no value. This update query is at bottom.

My search for a solution would indicate that I'm running against a pure limitation of updating the same record more than once in the same update query. However, I can't find an alternative or solution that isn't significantly more obtuse than the below. Is there a relatively simple way to update the same record/field more than once in the same update?

```
UPDATE purchaseOrders
SET purchaseOrders.notes =
        CASE 
            WHEN CHARINDEX(trackingInfo.tracking_no,purchaseOrders.notes) > 0
                THEN purchaseOrders.notes -- If tracking_no is already in notes, don't insert it.
            WHEN len(purchaseOrders.notes) = 0 OR purchaseOrders.notes IS NULL
                THEN '#' + trackingInfo.tracking_no -- If notes is empty, insert the tracking_no.
            ELSE purchaseOrders.notes + ', #' + trackingInfo.tracking_no -- If something is in notes, but it's not the tracking_no, then append the tracking_no.
        END     
FROM purchaseOrders
INNER JOIN trackingInfo ON purchaseOrders.po_no = trackingInfo.po_no
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to update the same record more once in the `UPDATE` query.  This can be done as a set-based operation with XML to facilitate concatenation:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.trackingInfo(
      po_no int NOT NULL
    , tracking_no varchar(10)  NOT NULL
    );

CREATE TABLE dbo.purchaseOrders(
      po_no int NOT NULL
    , notes varchar(MAX)  NULL
    );

INSERT INTO dbo.trackingInfo VALUES
      (1, 'ABC')
    , (2, 'DEF')
    , (2, 'GHI');

INSERT INTO dbo.purchaseOrders (po_no) VALUES
      (1)
    , (2);

UPDATE  dbo.purchaseOrders
SET     notes = STUFF(( SELECT  ', #' + tracking_no
                        FROM    dbo.trackingInfo AS ti
                        WHERE   ti.po_no = purchaseOrders.po_no
                      FOR
                        XML PATH('')
                      ), 1, 2, '');
```

Comment: But you are passing hard coded 1,2 values? How to avoid it?

Comment: @DevelopmentIsMyPassion, the data values are not hard-coded.  The literals `1 and 2` in the query are starting position and length arguments for the `STUFF` function.  This function removes the leading comma and space from the beginning of the concatenated string.

Comment: brilliant really. I was not aware